# JavaFX ImageCursor becoming corrupted and not displaying correctly

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX application that is using an ImageCursor. After some time, the cursor stops displaying the image and instead displays this:

[image: Sample]
(The "corrupted" cursor (notice the green lines, the yellow is the background of the app))

Why does this happen with the JavaFX ImageCursor class, and how do you prevent this?

NOTE: this only seems to happen when I click off the app and click back in.

Comment: To anyone who is curious, I ended up not using JavaFX's ImageCursor class and instead implemented this functionality using an ImageView that follows the cursor.